# How to make table table references capture section and begin each section?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I would like to have table labels refer the section that they are in in addition to the order. For example, in Appendix A, the first table is A1 and in Appendix B it is B1 (rather than table 1 and 2 respectively). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The results given in Table~\ref{tab:a} show the  performance of
the class.

 \section{Appendix A \label{app:a}}

\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lrc}\hline
        ABC & Mark & Grade \\
        \hline
        test & 100 & F \\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{XYZ}\label{tab:a}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}

 \section{Appendix B \label{app:a}}

\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lrc}\hline
        ABC & Mark & Grade \\
        \hline
        test & 0 & 'A \\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{XYZ}\label{tab:b}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}

 Table \ref{tab:a} and \ref{tab:b}...
```

In this, I would like the above to say Table A1 and Table B1 (rather than 1 and 2). Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: `\counterwithin{table}{section}` from the `chngcntr` package. Btw, don't use a `center` environment for tables and figures: it adds some more (unwanted) vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `table` environments should be numbered as `<section number>.<table counter>` in every section of the document, simply include the following lines of code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

If this numbering style should apply only to `table` environments located in the appendix section(s), you should provide the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,chngcntr}
\apptocmd{\appendix}{\counterwithin{table}{section}}{}{}
```

Of course, this recommendation assumes that you use the instruction `\appendix` at the start of the appendix portion of your document.